# Integration word problem

Tags: integration

A dam begins to release water into a stream at time $t=0$.
The total volume of water released by time $t$ satisfies the differential equation $$\frac{dV}{dt}=1400+60t$$ 
Solve this equation to find $V$.
I don't know how to calculate the value of $C$ from the information given.

Comment: What $C$ you want to calculate? Please show. (I guess that the $C$ is an integration constant, but please show how you get there.)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! We do not make a habit of answering questions where no effort is shown by the OP, nor simply doing homework. Try including what you've tried so far, and adding a bit of context to your question, so others are more willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to calculate the value of C from the information given.

From this comment I am assuming you have found $V(t\  ;C)$ where $C$ is some constant.
You are given what is sometimes referred to as an initial condition: $V(0) = 0$, since $V$ is measuring the amount of water released since $t=0$, it's a natural assumption that $V(t = 0) = 0$.
From this, you can create an equation:
$$0 = V(0\ ; C) = g(C)$$
and solve for your mysterious $C$.